# pdfTeX: set Minion Pro font only for specific document parts

Tags: fonts

I configured Minion Pro to correctly work with LaTeX through [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro).

I'd like to use it only for bold, bold italic, and section names, while being able to use any other font for text and math.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a job for fontspec. Do you have an MWE? (Also, welcome to TeX.SX!) Note that to use fontspec, you must use xetex/luatex which support native use of system fonts (which obviates fontpro).

Comment: The request is for plain `pdftex`, not `xetex` or `luatex`. I have a MWE and a sort of solution, I'll post it now for you to give me an opinion.

Comment: I recognize that, but I still think it's better suited for fontspec (which of course means *not* using pdftex – that's why I pointed it out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out a solution. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{MinionPro} % https://github.com/sebschub/fontpro
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% garamondx emph
% install it with https://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts
\let\emph\relax
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\emph}{\fontfamily{zgmx}\selectfont\em}

% minion pro bold
\let\textbf\relax
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textbf}{\fontfamily{MinionPro-LF}\selectfont\bfseries}

% minion pro bold italic
\newcommand{\bit}[1]{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}

% minion pro bold section
\titleformat{\section}
{\fontfamily{MinionPro-LF}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

normal, \emph{emph}, \textbf{bold} and \bit{bold italic}

\end{document}
```

The aim was to reproduce [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31743/85676), but in **pdfTeX**, and with [Garamond Expert](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/garamondx) as `\emph`.

[image: The result :)]

Comment: That is fairly grotesque, though, isn't it? especially the mis-matched italics....

Comment: I did not ask for an aesthetic opinion, though.

Comment: Indeed. In fact, it is an answer and not a question. Moreover both aesthetics and opinions are off-topic. But there is a certain degree of freedom in comments, I think, and TeX users are typically - although not necessarily - using TeX in part for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: My aim was just TeXnical, that's why I took the same freedom as you to reply.