# How to have both emphasis/italics and Chinese font

Tags: lyx, languages, cjk, emphasis

I'm creating a document in Lyx which has both Chinese and English characters. I need to be able to show emphasis through italics, but I cannot figure out a way to accomplish both. I changed the fonts, but then the fonts which allow Chinese do not also allow italics. I change them back, and then the italics show, but not the Chinese characters. Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!
J.D.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! How important is it to you to use Lyx while pursuing these typesetting-related goals?

Comment: Thank you! The document I am writing is a translation of a Chinese text from Chinese to English, with commentary, so it is very important. Certain important terms and the titles of references need to be shown in italics. However, since these terms and titles are all in English, I do not mind using a different font for italics than for the rest of the document. That may enable italics to function, however, I'm not sure how to do this on a document-scale. It wouldn't be feasible to change the font of each instance of an italicized word/words.

Comment: Thanks for these additional pieces of information. Regarding the use of Lyx as a front-end: How important is that to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mico, thank you for your help in replying to me so quickly! I was able to find a workaround, so I wanted to include it here in case others may find it useful.

I used this thread as a guide: [Specify different fonts for bold and italic with fontspec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31739/specify-different-fonts-for-bold-and-italic-with-fontspec)

I added this to my preamble by going to: [Document] > [Settings...] and then clicking on [LaTeX Preamble] in the left-hand column:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
BoldFont={Kaiti TC Bold},
ItalicFont={Times New Roman Italic},
BoldItalicFont={Times New Roman Bold Italic}
] {Kaiti TC}
```

**Kaiti TC** - font with Chinese capability

**Times New Roman** - English font

This is limiting in the following regard:

**Regular** - Chinese/English

**Bold** - Chinese/English

**Italic** - English only

**Bold Italic** - English only

There may be a pairing of fonts that is better than 'Kaiti TC' for Chinese and 'Times New Roman' for italics in English, but this is what I had tried just to see if it was working.

Thank you again and I hope this is helpful to others!
- J.D.

Edit: The font 'Baskerville' is an English font which also fits very well for italic/italic bold use with 'Kaiti TC' as the Chinese regular/bold font.