# Problem setting font with XeTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I want to use a font that's installed on my computer as my main font on a LaTeX document, which I'm compiling using XeLaTeX. Following [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31739/specify-different-fonts-for-bold-and-italic-with-fontspec) answer, I am using the following code

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
 BoldFont={Century Expanded Bold}, 
 ItalicFont={Century Expanded Medium Italic},
 BoldItalicFont={Century Expanded Bold Italic}
 ]{Century}
```

However, this returns the error

```
Package fontspec Error: The font "Century Expanded Bold" cannot be found.
```

My "Fonts" folder contains a font family called "Century". Within this family, there are all the fonts above. I guess the problem is that the fonts are inside the folder "Century" and not directly inside the folder "Fonts", but if I try to drag them out, Windows says "These fonts are already present, do you want to re-install them?" after which it re-installs them in the same folder "Century".

**EDIT** Turns out Century is a TTC rather than a folder. The rest of the above post should be correct.

Comment: Are you sure it is a folder and not a TTC? You can always specify the path to a font, so that LaTeX finds it.

Comment: You are correct, it is a TTC. Sorry.